# Setting pointer equal to a pointer in another method (within a loop)

Tags: java, for-loop, doubly-linked-list

I've tried solving my problem by searching for similar code, racking my brain, and even asking my computer science teacher but with no avail. This is part of a music database program I'm making for school, and currently I have problems setting the pointer in the main class equal to that in another class.

Here is a sample of the code that prints out for me when I attempted to find errors in my code:

What SHOULD print out:

```
Title: Numb
Artist: Linkin Park
Album:  Meteora
Genre: Rock
Title: Empty
Artist: JYJ
Album:  The Beginning
Genre: Pop
Title: Teardrops On My Guitar
Artist: Taylor Swift
Album:  N/A
Genre: Country
```

What my display method prints out:

```
DISPLAY
Title: Teardrops On My Guitar
Artist: Taylor Swift
Album:  N/A
Genre: Country
Title: Teardrops On My Guitar
Artist: Taylor Swift
Album:  N/A
Genre: Country
Title: Teardrops On My Guitar
Artist: Taylor Swift
Album:  N/A
Genre: Country
```

As you can see, it does print out three entries, but prints out the last one three times instead of each individual entry.

Here is the section of code I believe is the culprit of my issues, although I'm uncertain how to resolve them:

```
Node first = null;
int lines = edit.linesInFile();
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    first = edit.setNode(first, i);
    System.out.println(first.getData());
}
display.oneAtATime(first);
```

The print line within the for loop shows the output within the text file, so I know that the issue is not with putting the data in the main class or setting first equal to it within the loop.
However, the display does not show the same output as the print statement within the loop does.

Here is my oneAtATime method in my display class:

```
public void oneAtATime(Node ptr){
    System.out.println("DISPLAY");
    while(ptr != null){
        System.out.println(ptr.getData());
        ptr = ptr.getNext();
    }
}
```

ptr is simply a pointer that is returned by my method that sets the node's data to the music object that includes song title, artist, etc.

This is my first post and I'm uncertain as to what else I should include. If anything else is needed, feel free to let me know. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Okay, here's just all of the code I'm using so far. Have in mind a lot of it is a work in progress.

Here's my main class, called MusicMain.java:

```
package components;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MusicMain extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
static JTextField itemName = new JTextField(10);
static JTextField width = new JTextField(10);
static String radioText = "";
static JCheckBoxMenuItem yes;
Display display = new Display();
Edit edit = new Edit();

public MusicMain (){
    JButton mLButton = new JButton("Music List");
    mLButton.getPreferredSize();
    add(mLButton);
    mLButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            display.musicList();
        }
    });

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.getPreferredSize();
    add(addButton);
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            edit.add();
        }
    });

    JButton sortButton = new JButton("Sort");
    sortButton.getPreferredSize();
    add(sortButton);
    sortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            display.musicList();
        }
    });
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    JMenu submenu;

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Music Database");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("fire.jpg").getImage());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar grayMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JPanel unitsPanel = new JPanel();
    unitsPanel.setOpaque(true);
    unitsPanel.setBackground(new Color(128, 158, 182));
    unitsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    //Build the first menu.
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    grayMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
    grayMenuBar.setOpaque(true);
    grayMenuBar.setBackground(new Color(128, 158, 182));
    grayMenuBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    JMenu newSubmenu = new JMenu("New");
    newSubmenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    fileMenu.add(newSubmenu);
    JMenuItem newSong = new JMenuItem("Song");
    newSubmenu.add(newSong);
    JMenuItem newDB = new JMenuItem("Database");
    newSubmenu.add(newDB);
    fileMenu.add(newSubmenu);     

    JMenuItem loadDatabase = new JMenuItem("Load", KeyEvent.VK_L);
    fileMenu.add(loadDatabase);
    loadDatabase.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    });

    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_E);
    fileMenu.add(exit);
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel verify = new JLabel("Are you sure you would like to exit?");
            verify.setSize(120, 30);
            panel.add(verify);
            yes = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Yes");
            panel.add(yes);
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, 
            "Verification", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,  
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (yes.isSelected()){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });

    frame.setJMenuBar(grayMenuBar);

    MusicMain newContentPane = new MusicMain();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); 
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.setSize(200, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            Edit edit = new Edit();
            Info info = new Info();
            Display display = new Display();
            Node first = null;
            int lines = edit.linesInFile();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
                first = edit.setNode(first, i);
                System.out.println(first.getData());
            }
            display.oneAtATime(first);
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here's the code for my class called Display.java:

```
package components;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Display{
public void musicList(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Music List");
    frame.setSize(615,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setLayout(null);
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Song Title");
    JLabel artist = new JLabel("Artist");
    JLabel album = new JLabel("Album");
    JLabel genre = new JLabel("Genre");
    JLabel info = new JLabel("Info");
    title.setBounds(3,0,100,20);     
    artist.setBounds(169,0,100,20);
    album.setBounds(281,0,100,20);
    genre.setBounds(449,0,100,20);
    info.setBounds(562,0,100,20);

    frame.add(title);
    frame.add(artist);
    frame.add(album);
    frame.add(genre);
    frame.add(info);

    JPanel mL = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(0, 0);
    textArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Courier New", 0, 12));
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JPanel boxes = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    try{
        int count = 0;
        File file = new File("musiclist.txt");
        String text = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(text);
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            String token = tokens.nextToken(",");
            count++;
            int x = token.length();
            if (((count % 4) == 1) || ((count % 4) == 3)){
                if (x < 8){
                    textArea.append(token + "           ");
                }
                else if (x < 16){
                    textArea.append(token + "       ");
                }
                else{
                    textArea.append(token + "   ");
                }
            }
            else{
                if (x < 8){
                    textArea.append(token + "       ");
                }
                else{
                    textArea.append(token + "   ");
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (count / 4); i++){
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(22, 14));
            c.gridy = i;
            boxes.add(button, c);
        }
        d.weighty = 1;
        d.weightx = 1;
        d.gridx = 0;
        d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        d.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(mL);
        scroll.setBounds(0,20,600,343);
        mL.add(textArea, d);
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        mL.add(boxes, c);
        scroll.setViewportView(mL);
        frame.add(scroll);
        textArea.requestFocus();
    }
    catch(Exception e2){ 
        System.out.println(e2);
    }
}

public void oneAtATime(Node ptr){
    System.out.println("DISPLAY");
    while(ptr != null){
        System.out.println(ptr.getData());
        ptr = ptr.getNext();
    }
}
}
```

And here's the code for my class Edit.java:

```
package components;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Edit{
Node node = new Node();
Info info = new Info();
static JTextField titleField = new JTextField(20);
static JTextField artistField = new JTextField(20);
static JTextField albumField = new JTextField(20);
static JTextField genreField = new JTextField(20);


public Info setMusic(int d){
    try{
        FileReader in = new FileReader("musiclist.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String text = br.readLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
            text = br.readLine();
        }
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(text);
        int count = 0;
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            while (count < 4){
                String token = tokens.nextToken(",");
                count++;
                if (count == 1){
                    info.setTitle(token);
                }
                if (count == 2){
                    info.setArtist(token);
                }
                if (count == 3){
                    info.setAlbum(token);
                }
                if (count == 4){
                    info.setGenre(token);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e2){ 
        System.out.println(e2);
    }
    return info;
}

public int linesInFile(){
    int lines = 0;
    try{
        FileReader in = new FileReader("musiclist.txt");
        BufferedReader bd = new BufferedReader(in);
        while ((bd.readLine() != null)){
            lines++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e2){ 
        System.out.println(e2);
    }
    return lines;
}

public void add(){
    String sTitle = "";
    String sArtist = "";
    String sAlbum = "";
    String sGenre = "";

    JFrame addSong = new JFrame("Add Song");
    addSong.setSize(200,300);
    addSong.setVisible(true);
    addSong.setLayout(null);

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Song Title");
    JLabel artist = new JLabel("Artist");
    JLabel album = new JLabel("Album");
    JLabel genre = new JLabel("Genre");

    title.setBounds(3,0,100,20);     
    artist.setBounds(3,50,100,20);
    album.setBounds(3,100,100,20);
    genre.setBounds(3,150,100,20);

    titleField.setBounds(3,18,100,20);     
    artistField.setBounds(3,68,100,20);
    albumField.setBounds(3,118,100,20);
    genreField.setBounds(3,168,100,20);

    addSong.add(title);
    addSong.add(artist);
    addSong.add(album);
    addSong.add(genre);

    addSong.add(titleField);
    addSong.add(artistField);
    addSong.add(albumField);
    addSong.add(genreField);

    JButton addToList = new JButton("Add");
    addToList.getPreferredSize();
    addToList.setBounds(3,215, 100, 20);
    addSong.add(addToList);
    addToList.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            String sTitle = titleField.getText();
            String sArtist = artistField.getText();
            String sAlbum = albumField.getText();
            String sGenre = genreField.getText();

            try{
                Writer file;
                file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("musiclist.txt", true));
                file.append(sTitle + "," + sArtist + "," + sAlbum + "," + sGenre + "," + "\n");
                file.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e2){ 
                System.out.println(e2);
            }       
        }
    });
}
}
```

And here's the code for my class Info.java:

```
package components;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Info{
private String title;
private String artist;
private String album;
private String genre;

public void song(){
    String title = "";
    String artist = "";
    String album = "";
    String genre = "";
}

//Set methods
public void setTitle (String token){
    title = token;
}
public void setArtist (String token){
    artist = token;
}
public void setAlbum (String token){
    album = token;
}
public void setGenre (String token){
    genre = token;
}

//Get methods
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public String getArtist(){
    return artist;
}
public String getAlbum(){
    return album;
}
public String getGenre(){
    return genre;
}

public String toString(){
    String str;
    str = "Title: " + title + "\n" +
          "Artist: " + artist + "\n" +
          "Album:   " + album + "\n" +  
          "Genre: " + genre;
    return str;         
}
}
```

And finally the code for my class Node.java:

```
package components;

public class Node{
public Info data;
public Node next;
public Node previous;

public Node(){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    this.previous = previous;
}

public Info getData(){
    return data;
}

public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}

public Node getPrevious(){
    return previous;
}

public void setData(Info ob){
    data = ob;
}

public void setNext(Node n){
    next = n;
}

public void setPrevious(Node p){
    previous = p;
}
}
```

Some of the other functions don't work, but I can fix those later after I finally get the array to contain all of the songs listed in my text file.

Oh and the text file is just a text file in the same directory named musiclist.txt with each song in a separate line and formatted like so:

```
title1,artist1,album1,genre1,
title2,artist2,album2,genre2,
```

Attempt to use an ArrayList instead:

```
ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>();
for(int i = 0; i < edit.linesInFile(); i++){
    list.add(edit.setMusic(i));
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}

System.out.println("DISPLAY");
for(Info n: list){
    System.out.println(n.toString());
}
```

Comment: You don't say what a Node, edit, display is but I'm thinking this is some kind of LinkedList structure? Don't you want the Node going into oneAtATime to be the first item in the list....getFirst()?

Comment: Yes, this is a double linked list. Node is simply a generic node that gets and sets data, as well as provides getNext() and setNext() methods. 
As for my Edit class, there is a setMusic() method that reads the text file and sets the information in the file (like artist, song name, etc) to an object called info. 
As for my Display class, the only relevant method is the oneAtATime method shown previously which it contains.

Comment: You gotta add in a whole bunch more code.  This looks suspicious to me: `first = edit.setNode(first, i);` (having a setter return anything is odd)

Comment: @Taylor - agree everything looks a bit odd, where is the actual LinkedList structure? It looks like your just passing nodes of a list around? Where are setting the node to point to the next node? You're passing the last Node read to oneAtATime() - does the last node wrap to the first Node or something?

Comment: I added all relevant classes so hopefully that will help you all get a better idea of the program. The GUI part itself doesn't matter for my issue - I just need the linkedlist array to contain the entries listed in my text file.

Comment: Just FYI, java doesn't have "pointers". Title suggests possible confusion on this.

Comment: You are not having link to the other nodes while calling displayOneAtATime and you are pointing to the last node. So is the issue.
You need to revamp your code alot, why don't you use ArrayList or some other king f predefined Collections for your case.

Comment: I attempted to use an ArrayList as suggested, but I still encounter the same issue: the last song entry is printed three times, although within the loop itself I can see that every song is passed to the class correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is something like the type of function you should be using. Your node method is made in much more of a C++ pointer idea.

```
ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < edit.linesInFile(); i++{
    list.add(new Node(edit.getLine());
}
for(Node n: list){
    System.out.println(n.toString())
}
return list;
```

Why are you trying to store things inside the other class like you are?

But I guess for your C++ pointer node class maybe

```
Node mainNode = new Node();
for(int i = 0; i < edit.linesInFile(); i++{
    Node node = new Node()
    node.setVars("");
    ..  
    node.setPrevious(mainNode);
    mainNode.setNext(node);
    mainNode = node;
}
PrintF(mainNode)
```

This line seems bad to me

```
first = edit.setNode(first, i);
```

It should not return anything, maybe its the step that I have `mainNode = node;` I would need to see inside that specific method but basically what ever is inside there needs to do what I did.

Comment: I tried to implement an ArrayList as suggested and still encounter the same error. I added the code I placed into my main file to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Need to see your Edit class, specifically setEdit(), you should be using some funciton that returns a new node.

Comment: My Edit.java file code is listed in the first post. Since I'm working with ArrayLists now instead of a LinkedList, nodes are irrelevant, correct? My setMusic() method simply returns the info object containing the song title, artist, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String text = br.readLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        text = br.readLine();
    }
```

What you're doing is looping through the file, setting your text variable to each line of the file in turn.  When the loop finishes, you have the last line in that text variable.  That's why you're getting the last line repeated.  Your tokenization and setting the data fields on the info objects has to be inside that for loop.

I'm surprised your CS professor didn't find it.  :-)  Also you should close your BufferedReader in a finally block.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but that's not the issue. When I call my setMusic method, I pass in an int i that I loop through from my MusicMain.java file. So each time I run the loop, text = br.readLine(); will run through the for loop in my setMusic() method until it reaches the specified line and it will set each token to the info class and then return it. As you can see from the output I posted, this method functions as it was meant to - within the loop in the MusicMain.java file, it will print the appropriate information. However, the issue must have something to do with the list.

Comment: My teacher helped me resolve the issue, which was with having info declared globally, rather than within my setMusic() method.

Comment: Easy mistake to make.  If you find yourself setting something in a static non-final variable, stop and think if there's a way to pass it to a method instead, because that is less bug prone.